# How to Set Allowable Output Length in Maxima

Tags: maxima

Using Maxima, with batch file that is growing and doing more and me things, I've run into the following message:

"... [suppressed additional lines since the output is longer than allowed in the configuration] "

How can I set the "configuration" to allow more output?

Answer (score 1):

From the message, it appears you're using the wxMaxima user interface. Can you run your batch file with the command line interface? I.e. `maxima.exe --batch=yourbatchfile.mac` on Windows, or `maxima --batch=yourbatchfile.mac` on Unix-like systems.

That runs your batch file by itself. You can also launch the command line interface without any arguments, and then `batch("yourbatchfile.mac");` in your Maxima session.

There might also be a way to allow more output in wxMaxima; I don't use wxMaxima, so I don't know. But you could look at the configuration menu or menus to see if there is a flag or variable you can change.